# Why does the Image Uploader show "fakepath"?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Is there a reason the upload dialog shows a C:\fakepath\file instead of the real path 
or is it a bug?

[image]

Chromium 7.0.517.44 (64615) Ubuntu 10.10

UPDATE: In Firefox it 3.6.12 it shows only the file name without any path components,
so this is probably a Chromium browser bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting story, but not a bug:

[The image uploader shows "fakepath" as path when using Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68471/the-image-uploader-shows-fakepath-as-path-when-using-chrome)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.